# Proof of Generalized Primorial Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's call the numbers of the form $k\times p\# \mp1$, the Generalized Primorial Primes.

One can find many $k$ for a fixed $p$ such that $k\times p\# \mp1$ be prime. As an example for $p = 8933$ there are 13 $k$ below 20000.

I'd like to know, is there any way to prove (or even approach the proof) that there are *infinite* number of $k$ for each $p$?

1. $3347\times 8933\#+1$
2. $5570\times 8933\#+1$
3. $6980\times 8933\#+1$
4. $7227\times 8933\#+1$
5. $10087\times 8933\#+1$
6. $11731\times 8933\#+1$
7. $14532\times 8933\#+1$
8. $16957\times 8933\#+1$
9. $17173\times 8933\#+1$
10. $17575\times 8933\#+1$
11. $18563\times 8933\#+1$
12. $19518\times 8933\#+1$
13. $19625\times 8933\#+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a corollary of [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), which states that if $\gcd(a,d)=1$, then the arithmetic progression
$$a,\quad a+d,\quad a+2d,\quad\ldots$$
contains infinitely many prime numbers. For any prime number $p$, letting $d=p\#$  and $a=1$, we see that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form
$$k\cdot (p\#) +1.$$
For the minus case, just use $a=p\#-1$ instead.

Comment: Thank you, brilliant explanation ...

Comment: Glad to help!${}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we are assured of an infinite number of k's for the +1 case as well as another infinite set of k's for the -1 case, thanks to the result about arithmetic progressions mentioned above.  Are there an infinite number of k's that work for both the +1 and -1 cases simultaneously?  Prove it and you'll have shown that there are an infinite number of twin primes.